# TableView Cell Could not find member NSNumber variable

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Here is my code

```
 self.valueofID = json["id"] as? String
     NSLog("%@",  self.valueofID?)
```

Value that is return is something like "10122"

If I passes it as NSNumber, below cell shows error
Could not find member valueofID

```
 cell.detailTextLabel?.text = repositories[indexPath.row].valueofID!
```

I need to get the 10122 value from cell to pass to next class. Please provide some help on this

More info on array

```
   if let reposArray = jsonResult["results"] as? [NSDictionary] {

                    for item in reposArray {

                        self.repositories.append(Repository(json: item))

                    }
```

Comment: not clear question. You are creating a member named "description" & now  you are try to fetch "description" for  at an indexpath from array. Please explain clearly what you want to ask.

Comment: Sorry! my mistake
I edited the question... I unable to get the int value pass in cell indexpath

Comment: What type is self in the first snippet? How is your `repositories` array declared?

Comment: Edited my questions. please check @dan

Comment: Your edit didn't actually answer either of my questions.

Comment: var repositories = [Repository]() - my array declaration
Repository is another class from which I am calling self.valueofID

Comment: Hope it helps you understanding my issues.
And answers to your qeustions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to work it myself
First change it into NSNumber

```
 self.valueofID = json["id"] as? NSNumber
 NSLog("%@",  self.valueofID?)
```

It gives you value in NSNumber and then convert this value to NSString before passing into TableView cell. As it does not take NSNumber or int anything other than string

```
var mString2 : String? = String(stringInterpolationSegment:        
 repositories[indexPath.row].valueofID!)
```